Default contact_id in AfformSubmission
Is it possible to have a default contact_id whenever a form builder is submitted anonymously?

can you clarify what the goal is here?

@petednz-fuzion Currently, when trying to setup scheduled reminder with SavedSearch of AfformSubmission, it does not send an email to the manual recipient if AfformSubmission has null contact_id. It is null because it was submitted anonymously. The FormBuilder has "Verify submission before processing" checked. So we used Contact Field Id from "AfformSubmit".
When I tried to change the contact_id in the database, to an existing contact, the scheduled reminder was able to send an email, based on the Manual Recipient.
So I was thinking of setting a default contact_id.

The short answer is probably yes, depending.
But if it's being submitted anonymously, then the question is: 'what contact id do you want to be saved here?'.
The simple answer is that in the form builder, you can specific a default (e.g. to a contact called "anonymous").
But likely, even better, if that form url is getting sent via civimail, you can include the recipient's contact id in the url so that "their" contact id is encoded in the url and gets picked up by the form and saved.
